# Cannot update profile fields

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, error-message

I am unable to add experience or edit any fields. I can go into edit mode but after I click save it just says saving and waits. The same happends if I try to import from linked in. It says importing and nothing happens.

In chrome dev tools there seems to be a 500 error that keeps happening.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 InternalServerError
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-User-Id: 110820
X-User-Type-Id: 3
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2012 17:05:23 GMT
Content-Length: 9404
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: [what browser / version?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/165773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had some spurious data in one of the tables relating to tags, and it was preventing a save of Experience & Education for your particular profile. It’s been cleaned up, would you try it again?